# Unsold security in a delisted company

Tags: shares

I owned shares in a company called Transmode which was acquired by Infinera. As part of this acquisition 96% of the shareholders accepted an offer for their shares. I failed to do so as I was unwell at the time. If I understand correctly, I now own a security in Transmode which I can't sell since its no longer on the stock market. What options are available to me now? Do I have to wait a number of years before I see my money again? How much is my security worth?

Comment: Are you talking about having the original certificate? If so contact investor relations for Infinera. Let them know you own stock in Tansmode and that it was acquired by Infinera and they should tell you what you need to do.

Comment: `which I can't sell ` - No you can sell, but finding a buyer will be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

> As part of this acquisition 96% of the shareholders accepted an offer for their shares

This means that most of the shareholder agreed for the sale. If this was less than specified percentage, the deal would not have gone through. To make it easier, there were 2 options present to shareholder, full exchange of shares of Infinera or part shares and part cash.

> I failed to do so as I was unwell at the time

So you cannot now choose the option. There will be a default option of getting the equivalent shares in Infinera.

> What options are available to me now?

Contact Infinera investor relations and ask them.